# Remove Leading 0s in a text file

Tags: string, powershell

I have a file called `myfnames.txt` and it contains the ff below:

```
00000001
00000002
00000004
00000005
00000010
```

I want to remove the leading 0s but not the 0 on 00000010.

I'm trying to use `Trimstart('0')` but cant seem to get it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regex replace like so:

```
Get-Content myfnames.txt | % {$_ -replace '^0+', ''} | Set-Content NewFile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was already in the process of placing all of them in an array and looping it and use the trimstart, but this makes it easier :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply cast the values to integer:

```
$f = 'C:\path\to\myfnames.txt'
(Get-Content $f) | ForEach-Object { [int]$_ } | Set-Content $f
```

Other ways are the `-replace` operator that [@DaveSexton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36233450/1630171) suggested (`ForEach-Object` isn't required here, because the operator can be used directly on the array that `Get-Content` returns):

```
$f = 'C:\path\to\myfnames.txt'
(Get-Content $f) -replace '^0+' | Set-Content $f
```

or the `TrimStart()` method you said you had tried:

```
$f = 'C:\path\to\myfnames.txt'
(Get-Content $f) | ForEach-Object { $_.TrimStart('0') } | Set-Content $f
```

If you have at least PowerShell v3 you can simplify the latter to this:

```
$f = 'C:\path\to\myfnames.txt'
(Get-Content $f).TrimStart('0') | Set-Content $f
```

because since v3 PowerShell supports automatic unrolling of arrays, so you can transparently call a method on the members of an array by calling it on the array itself. Prior to v3 this would cause an error, because the array isn't unrolled and the array object itself doesn't have a method `TrimStart()`.

---

**Side note:** Either way, if you want to write the modified data back to the same file you need to run `Get-Content` in parentheses, so that it reads (and closes) the entire file before passing the data into the pipeline. Otherwise `Set-Content` would try writing to the file while it's still being read from, which would fail.